# changing the load item from a drop-down list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load different content into a div based on a drop-down selection. Here's the code so far:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var x;
    $('#loadCategory').change(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "videos"){
            x = 'videos.txt';
        }
        if ($(this).val() == "ads"){
            x = 'ads.txt';
        }
        if ($(this).val() == "widgets"){
            x = 'widgets.txt';
        }
        if ($(this).val() == "images"){
            x = 'images.txt';
        }else{
            x = 'videos.txt';
        }
    });
    $('.content').load(x,function(){
            $('img').wrap('<li></li>');
            $('.media-container').pajinate({
                items_per_page : 7
            });

            $( ".media-container li" ).draggable({
                appendTo: ".playlist ol",
                helper: "clone"
            });
    });
```

When I put "alert(x);" in the .change(), it shows me the correct  value, but doesn't change the content in .content. What am I missing?

Comment: Paginate or pajinate ? Getting any errors on page?

Comment: It only changes the content on first load, not on every change in the drop-down.

Comment: @sabithpocker I'll go take another coffee if that's the error! ;)

Comment: I think you need to move the load section into the onchange

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan ;) I'll get a coffee now

Comment: @sabithpocker: "pajinate" is the name of the pagination plugin I'm using. They spelled it that way, and it works fine when something is selected.

Comment: @sifujc thank you for taking the time to explain that :) Glad that your problem is fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#loadCategory').on('change', function(){
        loadContent(this.value+'.txt');
    });

    function loadContent(file) {
        $('.content').load(file, function(){
            $('img').wrap('<li></li>');
            $('.media-container').pajinate({
                items_per_page : 7
            });

            $( ".media-container li" ).draggable({
                appendTo: ".playlist ol",
                helper: "clone"
            });
        });
    }
});
```

if the `else` statement is really needed you could always do:

```
$('#loadCategory').on('change', function(){
    var t = this.value,
        x = (t=='videos'||t=='ads'||t=='widgets'||t=='images')?this.value:'videos';
    $('.content').load(x+'.txt', function(){
        $('img').wrap('<li></li>');
        $('.media-container').pajinate({
            items_per_page : 7
        });

        $( ".media-container li" ).draggable({
            appendTo: ".playlist ol",
            helper: "clone"
        });
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    loadContent('videos.txt');

    $('#loadCategory').on('change', function(){
        loadContent(this.value+'.txt');
    });

    function loadContent(file) {
        $('.content').load(file, function(){
            $('img').wrap('<li></li>');
            $('.media-container').pajinate({
                items_per_page : 7
            });

            $( ".media-container li" ).draggable({
                appendTo: ".playlist ol",
                helper: "clone"
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This code is not equivalent to the original. Will work differently.

Comment: Nope, it works and does exactly what the original should have done, thanks for the downvote!

Comment: @adaneo So when `this.value` is not one of the listed values, it will load `videos.txt`? (of course it will always be `videos.txt` when the value is not `images`, because the logic is messed up in the OP's code)

Comment: +1 for improving the code, but note that there is an `else` statement.

Comment: @Raminson - yes there is, and that else statement is a really bad idea. Either it's one of the selected options, or it is'nt.

Comment: @adeneo what makes a default option _a really bad idea_?

Comment: @adaneo I would not call it a bad idea. My other reasons for the downvote: giving a "cool" solution to a beginner who has problems with the basics and not explaining anything. You might have shown yourself that you can solve this problem in a way that might seem elegant to you, but this site is not really about this. Why did you use a function there?

Comment: Because a function made more sense to me, it seperates the two functions, and it seems easier to follow that logic, atleast for me it does. Just added another alternative, I'd go for the first one, but atleast the second one should make you happier.

Comment: @adeneo OK, but how should he know these things when you don't explain? I promise I could write this code in a much more elegant way,  but this is not a programming contest here :). ps: the second one does not make me happier, because you introduce even more stuff without explanation.

Comment: @Raminson - It's not really a default option. It's inside the change function, and it sees if the value matches any of the four first options and if it does'nt it loads the "default". If the drop down list only contains those four options, it's completely unesseccary, and if the list contains many more options, that same file will be loaded over and over on any change that does not match one of the first four options. It just seems like a bad idea to me, and not something I would do if I could avoid it.

Comment: @bažmegakapa - If the OP got that far, implementing if/else statements, different plugins and loading of dynamic content, he probably gets what's going on in a simple function? Should we assume that everyone who asks a question is an idiot and needs every simple aspect of javascript explained in detail.

Comment: @adeneo I don't want to make this any longer, but: he misplaced the function call, implemented the if/else statements in a wrong way (which is absolutely acceptable from a noob, before anybody misinterprets). Using plugins and loading content from txt files is simple copy-paste. I'm off, by now you can understand my point if you intend to, if not, it's just a waste of time.

Comment: @adeneo, the else statement was intended to put a default view on the page so the users aren't just looking at a blank field when the page loads. This is why I was declaring the value at the top, since a value isn't assigned until the select box is selected, so maybe else isn't the right choice, since it's still acting as if nothing is defined until the selection happens when I try your second code and bazmegakapa's code below... This is the first time I've tried to do something like this, rather than just telling the developers to make it happen, so thank you for your help and patience.

Comment: @sifujc - Just load the content on first page load, then use the function for option change etc. See my edited code above.

Answer (score 1):

You want to execute the loading part when the `change` event occurs - so you need to move that code into the event handler for that event:

```
//assign the event handler
$('#loadCategory').change(function(){
    //prepare the value of x
    //corrected your conditions by adding else
    if ($(this).val() == "videos"){
        x = 'videos.txt';
    }
    else if ($(this).val() == "ads"){
        x = 'ads.txt';
    }
    else if ($(this).val() == "widgets"){
        x = 'widgets.txt';
    }
    else if ($(this).val() == "images"){
        x = 'images.txt';
    }
    else{
        x = 'videos.txt';
    }

    //load the right content based on x
    $('.content').load(x,function(){
            $('img').wrap('<li></li>');
            $('.media-container').pajinate({
                items_per_page : 7
            });

            $( ".media-container li" ).draggable({
                appendTo: ".playlist ol",
                helper: "clone"
            });
    });    
});
```

In your original code, this is what happens:

- declare the local variable `x` (`undefined`)
- assign the change event handler
- load the content based on `x`, which is `undefined` at that time!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `$('.content').load()` in your change event handler.

Also all those if statements seem a bit redundant.  Try using a switch statement.

```
switch ($(this).val()) {
    case "videos":
        x = "videos.txt";
        break;
    case "widgets":
        x = "widgets.txt";
        break;
    ... etc ..
}
```

Or maybe even

```
x = $(this).val() + ".txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put your content load into function hooked to "change" event.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#loadCategory').change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "videos"){
        x = 'videos.txt';
    }
    if ($(this).val() == "ads"){
        x = 'ads.txt';
    }
    if ($(this).val() == "widgets"){
        x = 'widgets.txt';
    }
    if ($(this).val() == "images"){
        x = 'images.txt';
    }else{
        x = 'videos.txt';
    }

    $('.content').load(x,function(){
        $('img').wrap('<li></li>');
        $('.media-container').pajinate({
            items_per_page : 7
        });

        $( ".media-container li" ).draggable({
            appendTo: ".playlist ol",
            helper: "clone"
        });


  });
```

if you still want it to load at first time then put the load section in a function and call the function in the onchange